# Associate with same model on Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  sequence :api_name do |n|
    "API_License_Name_#{n}"
  end

  factory :api_license do
    name { FactoryGirl.generate(:api_name) }
    description "Desc" 
  end 
end
```

But on two specific factories I have the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :scope_permission do
      permission
      action
   end
end
```

"Permission" and "Action" are both factories which are both related to api_license. For example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :action do
    name "My Action"
    api_license
  end
end
```

The problem is that permission and action are being linked to different api_licenses (two of them are being created).

What can I do to make them related to the same api license?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to handle this scenario either by using a callback or a custom constructor.

With a callback, you will create the second association after the factory is finished, which will give you access to the first associated model's parameter.

Here's the docs:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks

With a custom constructor (may be necessary in this case), you can use an `ignore do` block and create the association with objects you've already built. It would look something like this:

```
ignore do
  api_license create(:api_license)
  permission create(:permission, api_license: api_license)
  action create(:action, api_license: api_license)
end



initialize_with do
  new(permission: permission, action: action)
end
```

There's a simpler example that's not quite as close to what you need to do in the Factory Girl GETTING STARTED file:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction

Comment: I don't understand very well. I have one file per factory. Where should this code go?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show the code that wraps this segment. My snippet goes inside the factory :scope_permission do / end block, it's the contents of your factory.

Comment: I get the following error: definition_proxy.rb:35:in `add_attribute': wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) (ArgumentError)